How to prepare Homebrew for running on a soon to be unsupported OS
How can I use pin, tap and --build-from-source or other solutions in order to make sure an unintentionally triggered update or upgrade does not cripple my system?

As long as you don‘t run brew upgrade, everything already installed will work as before. What exactly is your goal here?

Sometimes updates/upgrades are triggered automatically, when something is installed. This happened to me when Mojave was unsupported by homebrew. I would like to learn how to keep my system working after they strip Monterey support.

I understand that the formulae get updated, when Homebrew is updated. I could pin a formulae to freeze it apparently, but I do not know how the tap and --build-from-source works and how to orchestrate the three in order to not end with important apps crippled after an update/upgrade is triggered somehow...

You will miss any security changes to the programs - it might be worth switching to Macports which does support older versions of macOS - it is best efforts but some things are supported back to Tiger.

How can you use Homebrew still to install stuff once it‘s not supported on your version of macOS anymore?

That is what I am trying to find out. I could write my own formula, but that would probably not require a brew update. For now I decided to back up everything (brew and homebrew-core) and forked it too. I used to have a dev machine with Mojave some years ago. There somehow an auto-update, auto-upgrade was triggered during a brew install and part of the dev stack was gone, because something did not compile properly. I am trying to prevent this for the time being.

It has lost support already!  brew upgrade on Monterey now shows: “Warning: You are using macOS 12.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this old version.
It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow. […]”

They just added the message. It should still work 100%, but devs will not give support in case something goes wrong. At a certain point devs will release a version with a notice in the changelog that they dropped Monterey until then it should be ok to update. You might be able to update for some time without problems, but when certain dependencies will require newer versions of macOS there will be build problems and certain knowledge is required to try to get things working.

If a brew update or brew update && brew upgrade is triggered on an unsupported version of macOS automatically through Homebrew or intentionally by the user potential issues might be related in general:

to newer releases of Homebrew not being 100% compatible with
the OS or
to formula having stricter requirements such as for
newer underlying C-libraries

This can result in formulae failing to build and, depending from the severity, in a crippled system environment. This might not happen immediately after a version of the OS is declared unsupported but with time the likelihood increases. Solving these problems requires the necessary knowledge and might result in writing your own formula, using other tools or installing the required applications directly.
The main cause of trouble is that someone might be trying to brew install an application that is already part of the local Homebrew-core formulae or maybe to brew reinstall an already installed application. The official Homebrew is configured in a way that forces an update of Homebrew and the underlying formulae collection (homebrew-core) before certain operations, such as installations.
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install <formula> is a way on older systems to avoid the auto-update procedure before installations.
brew pin <formula> can be used to freeze a formula excluding it from a potentially triggered update/upgrade. But even if a formula is pinned, an update to applications it relies on might produce issues.
In case a brew update/upgrade is triggered unintentionally and something does not compile correctly, it is often the best solution to have a full backup of the /usr/local directory, since troubleshooting an unsuccessful upgrade process with multiple upgraded applications, their dependencies, might be too complex or time consuming to troubleshoot, if the error message is not precise enough.
brew tap allows to add your own formula. Whereas official formulae are provided by the homebrew-core repository. brew tap can add repositories of your own. Each tap is a repository, which can hold multiple formulae each.
You would:
brew tap <user/repo>
brew install customFormula

In case a custom formula has the same name as an official formula the custom formula has to be installed through:
brew install user/repo/formula

